# How to Insert timestamp record automatically create in database when we clicked button insert in Java Swing?

Tags: java, postgresql, swing, datetime, timestamp

How to insert datetime use timestamp when I clicked button insert, I get datetime data and insert into database postgresql in automatic insert like auto increment, auto fill column in database use java swing on eclipse

This is my code for Entity

```
public class KeyEntity {

private Long id_company;
private Date creationDate;
private String KeyEncrypted;
//static Connection conn =null;

private static final String url ="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/securityFile";
private static final String user = "postgres";
private static final String password = "root";

public static Connection koneksi() {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn= DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        System.out.println("Database berhasil terkoneksi");

    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Koneksi Gagal");
    }
    return conn;

}

public Long getId_company() {
    return id_company;
}

public void setId_company(Long id_company) {
    this.id_company = id_company;
}

public Date getCreationDate(Long time) {
    return creationDate;
}

public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
}

public String getKeyEncrypted() {
    return KeyEncrypted;
}

public void setKeyEncrypted(String keyEncrypted) {
    KeyEncrypted = keyEncrypted;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Key [id_company=" + id_company + ", creationDate=" + creationDate + ", KeyEncrypted=" + KeyEncrypted
            + "]";
}

}
```

This is my code Controller

```
public class KeyController {
Connection koneksi= null;
ResultSet res = null;
Statement sttm = null;
String sql = null;

public KeyController() {
    koneksi();
}

private void koneksi() {
    try {
        sttm =(Statement)KeyEntity.koneksi().createStatement();
    }catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

Date date = new Date();

Long time = date.getTime();
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(time);

public boolean tambahKey(KeyEntity key) {
    String sqlKey = "INSERT INTO tb_key VALUES('"
            +key.getCreationDate(time)+"','"
            +key.getKeyEncrypted()+"')'";
    try {
        sttm.executeUpdate(sqlKey);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Berhasil Disimpan");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pastikan Data terisi Dengan Benar "+e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

This is my code in Java Interface, I use auto increment in id_Company

```
    JButton btnInsertKey = new JButton("Insert Key");
    btnInsertKey.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            KeyEntity keyEntity = new KeyEntity();
            keyEntity.setId_company(id_company.getText());
            keyEntity.setCreationDate(creationDate.getText());
            keyEntity.setKeyEncrypted(lblKey.getText());

            if(koneksi.tambahKey(keyEntity)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Key berhasil ditambahkan didatabase");
            }else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Key gagal ditambahkan didatabase");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I would believe that in PostgreSQL you can define a column whose value defaults to current timestmap. Please check. If you prefer to define the current timestamp from Java, of curse that is possible too.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use something like `OffsetDateTime` or `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Does your code work? What error or other inadequate behaviour do you observe? Such information is crucial since we want to know that we are helping you with the correct problem, not a different one.